# Selecting records in order of the number of records that contain a certain field

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table that is arranged as such: ID, Album_ID and Time_Voted. Each time a user votes, 
it creates a new record. We'd like to display the top five Album_IDs, (which had the most records containing that Album_ID at the end of every week). The only way I know how to do this is to SELECT all records from the past week, then run a "while" on the results,then iterate through an array and and add a +1 to the corresponding Album_ID key each time it finds an instance of the same Album_ID. This is quite inefficient, and I'm convinced there's a good way to do this via SQL query, but it's beyond my level of knowlege.

So the question is, is there a way to, via query, get a count of each number of album_IDs, and then arrange by that count?

Here's the original SQL statement I was working with. The YEARWEEK stuff was just to get last week.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_album_votes WHERE YEARWEEK( Time_Voted ) = YEARWEEK( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ORDER BY Album_ID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Album_ID, COUNT(*) AS NumVotes 
    FROM wp_album_votes 
    WHERE YEARWEEK( Time_Voted ) = YEARWEEK( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY ) 
    GROUP BY Album_ID
    ORDER BY NumVotes DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Bah, you beat me to it by 6 seconds :)

Comment: Perfect! If only I could give 2 correct answers! Guess a +1 will have to do!

Answer (score 1):

```
select album_id, count( album_id ) 
from wp_album_votes
group by album_id
order by 2 desc.
```

you can wrap your other text and dates onto this basic structure...